# R: dynamic construction and execution of commands

Tags: r, shiny

Based on user input, I need to use a different color palette. User input can take on four (character) values: `gray`,`heat`,`terrain`, and `rainbow`. Instead of writing a series of if statements, it would be elegant to directly do something like:

`palette = cat(user_input,".colors(n=10)",sep="")` or same with `paste0`...

`cat(user_input,".colors(n=10)",sep="")` does give me `gray.colors(n=10)` but it is just pasted text, not an evaluated command, so nothing happens and if I save the output as the `palette` object it is just the text that is being saved.

*Note: sorry if the wording of the title is not appropriate. I am not from CS and I don't know how this task should be called. And to give some context, this is for a shiny app*.

Comment: Well, as a start, don't use `cat`. It doesn't return a value to the R workspace. Sounds like you may want `parse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to evaluate the parsed text:

```
> eval(parse(text="gray.colors(n=10)"))
 [1] "#4D4D4D" "#6C6C6C" "#838383" "#969696" "#A7A7A7" "#B5B5B5" "#C3C3C3"
 [8] "#CFCFCF" "#DBDBDB" "#E6E6E6"
```

Any text can be evaluated and run this way. Note that if this string can be set by a user and sent to a server there may be a way for them to run arbitrary code on your server. Make sure you validate the allowed palette functions on the server before running code from clients like this (search for "XKCD Bobby Tables" for more).

Another option is using `do.call`, which works with character strings of function names:

```
> do.call("gray.colors",list(n=10))
 [1] "#4D4D4D" "#6C6C6C" "#838383" "#969696" "#A7A7A7" "#B5B5B5" "#C3C3C3"
 [8] "#CFCFCF" "#DBDBDB" "#E6E6E6"
```

and is probably less vulnerable to code injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making your app too complicated; you don't need `eval` here. Instead, present the user with a choice of palettes, then use that to look up the function from a list.

Here is an example based on the old faithful example that comes with shiny:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # List of palette functions
  my_palettes <- list(Rainbow=rainbow,
                      Heat=heat.colors,
                      Terrain=terrain.colors,
                      Topo=topo.colors)

  # Provide a drop down for palette
  output$palette <- renderUI(selectInput("palette", "Palette:", names(my_palettes), names(my_palettes)[1]))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # look up palette function from list, call it with n=bins
    palette = my_palettes[[input$palette]](input$bins)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = palette, border = 'white')
  })

})
```